# Can't figure out why my "Logon" class returns nothing

Tags: c#, sql

So I am trying to make a login screen where the input from a textbox has to match a username and password from a database. It's probably something stupid but I can't figure out why it's not working. 
This is my first time using stackoverflow so if I did anything wrong feel free to point it out.

This is my Logon class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Logon
    {
        public static Users Login(string Gebruiker, string Wachtwoord)
        {
            Users NewUser = new Users();
            SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection();


            string Username = "SELECT Username FROM Gegevens WHERE Username = @Username";

            SqlCommand username = new SqlCommand(Username, connection);
            username.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Gebruiker);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader GetUsername = username.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

                if (GetUsername.Read())
                {
                    NewUser.Username = GetUsername["Username"].ToString();
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

            finally { connection.Close(); }

            string Password = "SELECT Password FROM Gegevens WHERE Password = @Password";

            SqlCommand password = new SqlCommand(Password, connection);
            password.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Wachtwoord);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader GetPassword = password.ExecuteReader();


                if (GetPassword.Read())
                {

                    NewUser.Password = GetPassword["Password"].ToString();

                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex2)
            {

                throw ex2;
            }
            finally { connection.Close(); }

            return NewUser;

        }
    }
}
```

User class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Users
    {

        private string username;
        private string password;

        public Users() { }
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }
        public string Password  
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Finally the button itself:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Users NewUser;

            string User = txtUsername.Text;
            string Pass = txtPassword.Text;


            NewUser = Logon.Login(User, Pass);

            if (User == NewUser.Username && Pass == NewUser.Password)
            {
                Form1 ls = new Form1();
                ls.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _returns nothing_? Do you have an exception message?, or what is the observed behavior of the code above?. Note that you really don't need to use two queries to find if your user exists or not.

Comment: It seems like the Logon class isn't executed while it should be whenever I click the "accept" button. When I check the values of NewUser.Username its null. I also don't get the exception messages.

Comment: @Can'tC Did you verify if values are correctly passed to Login function and those values are present in database table?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Code inside `if(GetUsername.Read())` is executed?

Comment: When debugging and checking the return values of NewUser they're all null. When I add a textbox to check the value (like this: txtTest.Text = NewUser.Username.ToString();) I get "System.NullReferenceException". I assume because NewUser is null. I don't get errors at my connectionstrings

Answer (score 0):

You should use one query to validate user credentials like

```
SELECT top 1 1 FROM Gegevens WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password
```

Answer (score 0):

### Implementation points

A couple of things I can see in your code:

```
string Password = "SELECT Password FROM Gegevens WHERE Password = @Password";
```

It will not validate that the user has the target password, but will just return multiple times the password you are looking for, from all the users that happen to use it.

Better use one query like this

```
string userQuery = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Gegevens WHERE Username = "@Username" and Password =
    @Password";
```

Second issue is with how you retrieve the data from the password query.

```
NewUser.Username = GetUsername["Username"].ToString();
```

Change it to something like this

```
SqlDataReader userReader = userQueryExecuteReader();

if (userReader.Read())
{
     NewUser.Username = userReader[0].ToString();
     NewUser.Password = userReader[1].ToString();
}
```

### Debugging help

You can debug step by step your code by placing breakpoints. [MS guidance here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019). Please do that, and let us know what the exact error, or where your code stops. Then we can help you solve the exact issue.

Welcome to SO.

Comment: I have changed the class. When debugging and checking the return values of NewUser they're all null. When I add a textbox to check the value (like this:  txtTest.Text = NewUser.Username.ToString();) I get "System.NullReferenceException". I assume because NewUser is null. I don't get errors at my connectionstrings or query.

Comment: Can you please add a breakpoint in the `public static Users Login(string Gebruiker, string Wachtwoord)` Does the query return something when you watch the datareader?

Comment: When debugging the class step by step it seems like 

if (reader.Read())
            {
                NewUser.Username = reader[0].ToString();
                NewUser.Password = reader[1].ToString();
            }
Isn't executed. The "value" of reader is this:
reader {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader} System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Comment: Sorry, seems you missed something in your comment. What does it seem like? What happens during the `if(reader.Read())`. It never gets in there? That would make sense. No matches in the database for this username and password would not return anything and you would have null without user values.

Comment: Do the `string Gebruiker, string Wachtwoord` have values when you debug step by step?

Comment: I'm starting to figure it out. I wasn't passing the right values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept/upvote helpful answers :)